# Windows Service That Deletes Contents of C:\Windows\Temp

Tags: windows, vb.net, service

I have windows service written in vb.net that deletes the contents of a folder (meaning all files, subfolders, and files) in that folder every few minutes.

I need to change the service so that it now deletes the contents of the C:\Windows\Temp folder.

When I edit the path in the service, then recompile, and re-install, the service does not delete the contents of C:\Windows\Temp

I even added code to handle any open/locked files so that the deletion process would just continue, but still nothing.

```
    Sub ClearWinTempDirectory(folder As String)
    'Loop over the subdirectories and remove them with their contents
    For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(folder)
        Directory.Delete(d, True)
    Next

    ' Finish removing also the files in the root folder
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(folder)
        Try
            File.Delete(f)
        Catch e As System.IO.IOException
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try
    Next

    COBWtl.WriteEntry("All files and folders in the " & folder & " directory that   
    are not currently locked by applications or processes Have been deleted", 
    EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID:=9995)
End Sub
```

I am hoping someone can help me identify why this service does not work when pointed to C:\Windows\Temp but it works without incident when deleting files and folders in C:\MyTestFolder.

My service runs as LocalSystem and SYSTEM has full control on C:\Windows\Temp

I also changed it to run as an administrator account, but that doesn't work either.

I can put the same code into a non-service exe and double click it, and it works and deletes the contents of C:\Windows\Temp -- so I am at a complete loss and hope someone can point me in the right direction on how to figure out what is wrong.

I provided process monitor results, which appear to show the service is accessing C:\windows\temp which is confusing because I put some test files out there that are not open or held up in a process, and those are not being deleted.

[Native Process Monitor PML Results File](http://www.aloye.com/docs/procmon/COBClearWinTmp.PML)

[Process Monitor Extended Results XML File](http://www.aloye.com/docs/procmon/COBClearWinTmp.xml)

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: I did, and they deleted my post as being off topic

Comment: What makes you think it's on-topic here?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand exactly how or where things need to be posted in stackexchange. I thought I posted it to the programmers area with tags of VB.Net, Windows, and Service... maybe I didn't post it in the right place. First time I am posting on stack exchange.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my own problem. Here is what I found:

The service was successfully accessing C:\Windows\Temp but it was failing due to two exceptions:

1) Permissions Exception where it was denied access to a subfolder or file as a result of permissions

2) IO Problem because the file was open or in use.

In my code, I was only checking for System.IO.Exceptions so when it encountered an Access Failure exception it would break.

Once I discovered this, I modified the exception handling on the catch so that it would check for all exceptions.

Hence the code changed from what it was as listed above to this.

```
Sub ClearWinTempDirectory(folder As String)
    'Loop over the subdirectories and remove them with their contents
    For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(folder)
        Try
            Directory.Delete(d, True)
        Catch e As System.Exception
            COBWtl.WriteEntry("The directory " & d & " is 
            currently locked or is inaccessable and will not be deleted.", 
            EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID:=9997)
        End Try
    Next
    ' Finish the files in the root folder
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(folder)
        Try
            File.Delete(f)
        Catch e As System.Exception
            COBWtl.WriteEntry("The file " & f & " in directory " & folder  
            & " is currently locked or is inaccessable and will not be 
            deleted.", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID:=9997)
        End Try
    Next

    COBWtl.WriteEntry("All files and folders in the " & folder & " 
    directory that are not currently locked by applications or processes 
    Have been deleted", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID:=9995)
 End Sub
```

Problem solved.